# Looking for a PHP Image Library... rounded corners & resizing

Tags: php, image-processing

Just looking for a good PHP Image Library, I want to display images with rounded corners, do some resizing, and blur some other pictures either on the fly, or on upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to have a look around ImageMagick.

There are excellent wrappers for the library in PHP too: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php

Answer (score 4):

Have a go with http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wiki/MainPage

It doesn't do it out of the box but you could have a partially transparent PNG that you could put on top of your original image, making it blurry.

Comment: It is straightforward and good indeed.

Answer (score 1):

this is a dirty hack i did for a project a while ago. it applies an grayscale image as a  transparency map to another image (black is transparent, white opaque. scaling the map to the images proportions is supported). you could create a fitting rounded-corners transparency map (including antialiasing, whoo!).

it's slow because it's pure php, but i always cache the results anyway.

$image and $transparencyMap are gd image ressources, so you have to imagecreatefromxyz them yourself.

```
<?php
function applyTransparencyMap($image, $transparencyMap) {
    if (!function_exists('extractrgb')) {
        function extractrgb($rgb) {
            $a = ($rgb >> 24) & 0xFF;
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            return array($r, $g, $b, $a);
        }
    }

    $sx = imagesx($image);
    $sy = imagesy($image);
    $tx = imagesx($transparencyMap);
    $ty = imagesy($transparencyMap);
    $dx = $tx / $sx;
    $dy = $ty / $sy;

    $dimg = imagecreatetransparent(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

    for ($y = 0; $y<imagesy($image); $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x<imagesx($image); $x++) {
            $intcolor                = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $intalpha                = imagecolorat($transparencyMap, floor($x*$dx), floor($y*$dy-1));
            list($tr, $tg, $tb, $ta) = extractrgb($intalpha);
            $alphaval                = 127-floor(($tr+$tg+$tb)/6);
            list($r, $g, $b, $a)     = extractrgb($intcolor);
            $targetAlpha             = max(0, min(127,$alphaval+$a));
            $sct                     = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, $r, $g, $b, $targetAlpha);
            imagesetpixel($dimg, $x, $y, $sct);
        }
    }

    return $dimg;
}
?>
```

on the other hand, better use [wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wiki/MainPage), as apikot suggested. does the same and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this library http://freelogic.pl/thumbnailer/examples

Comment: You should have mention this is a commercial library.